# Operações com números complexos em C - Cálculo de raízes de uma equação pelo método de Newton Raphson

Tags: c, análise-numérica

Estou com um problema em um programa de linguagem C que calcula a raiz de uma equação utilizando o método de Newton-Raphson, mais especificamente quando a equação apresenta raízes complexas.

No meu caso a equação que estou utilizando terá raízes reais se a constante `c` da equação for menor do que zero. Para `c` maior que zero, a equação terá raízes complexas.

Estou com o seguinte código, onde apresento o valor de `c = 0.99` e o programa consegue rodar e obter a raiz real de `5.796753`.

Se o valor de c for alterado para qualquer valor maior que 1 o programa entra em um laço infinito e nunca converge.

Alguém teria alguma ideia do que deveria ser feito para convergir em uma raiz complexa?

Estou passando o código em C:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<complex.h>

#define c 0.99
#define e 0.00000000000000001
#define F(x) ((c/2)*((log(x+1)-log(x-1))+(2*x/(x*x-1))))

float frac(float a)
{
    float f1;
    f1=(1-((c*a/2)*(log(a+1)-log(a-1))));
    return f1;
}

int main()
{
    float x1,x2,f1=0,f2,er,d;
    printf("F(x) = 1-{(c*x/2)*[log(a+1)-log(x-1)]}\n\n");
    printf("Entre com o valor de x1: ");
    scanf("%f",&x1);
    printf("\nx1 = %f",x1);
    printf("\n________________________________________________________________________________\n");
    printf("     x1      |       x2      |      f1       |       f'1      |  |(x2-x1)/x2|  |  \n");
    printf("--------------------------------------------------------------------------------\n");
    do
    {
        f1=frac(x1);
        d=F(x1);
        x2=x1-(f1/d);
        er=fabs((x2-x1)/x2);
        printf("  %f   |    %f   |     %f  |     %f  |      %f  |   \n",x1,x2,f1,d,er);
        x1=x2;
    }
    while(er>e);
    printf("--------------------------------------------------------------------------------\n\n");
    printf("\n  A raiz da equacao: %f",x2);
    getch();
}
```

Comment: Cuidado ao fazer `#defines` com nomes como `c`, `e` e `F(x)` pois isso pode causar erros obscuros. É melhor você criar uma `const float` para `c` e `e` e `F(x)` uma funções mesmo.

Comment: Não use `float` para trabalhar com frações, a precisão dele é muito baixa. Use o `double` ou `long double`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se está entrando em um loop infinito, o problema está no `while(er>e);`, que deve ser sempre verdadeira. Desta forma, deveria verificar se a atribuição que fazes a `er` está correta: `er=fabs((x2-x1)/x2);`, além de verificar se o valor definido para a constante `e` também está correto.
Como você está utilizando `fabs`, está pegando somente valores positivos, que, para o range de um float, por menor que seja (diferente de 0), será sempre maior que `e`. Sugiro que utilize `double` no lugar de `float` para uma maior precisão, e que diminua ligeiramente a precisão de `e` para maior exatidão.